# Not able to connect to internet from guest OS using qemu-kvm

Tags: qemu

I am trying to emulate **FreeBSD** (**RISC-V 64**) using QEMU-KVM
on a **x86-64 host running Debian**. I have installed the required
packages `qemu-system-riscv64` (from `qemu-system-misc`), `opensbi`
and downloaded FreeBSD kernel and rootfs image from [this link](https://artifact.ci.freebsd.org/snapshot/14.0-CURRENT/latest/riscv/riscv64/).

**First**, I tried with **virt-manager** which didn't provide me the
option to set the bios path to `opensbi/generic/fw_jump.elf`. I
was able to set the kernel path but the VM didn't boot up, showed
an error containing the following :

`'riscv64' architecture is not supported by CPU driver`

**Second**, I booted it directly using `qemu-system-riscv64` along
with the options mentioned at the [FreeBSD Wiki page](https://wiki.freebsd.org/riscv) and to be
specific I used the option `-device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22`. This time the VM booted
up with `root` user. However I can't access the internet
from inside the host :

- `ping google.com` gives `unknown host`
- `ping 8.8.8.8` gives `No route to host`
- Tried installing the package management tool but that gives the
  following error

`pkg: Error fetching http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:14:riscv64/latest/Latest/pkg.txz: Non-recoverable resolver failure`
`Address resolution failed for http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:14:riscv64/latest. Consider changing PACKAGESITE`

I tried setting up tap networking following [this link](https://blog.stefan-koch.name/2020/10/25/qemu-public-ip-vm-with-tap). I am
using a wireless connection which shows up as `wlp2s0` (guess this
should replace `eth0` as mentioned in the tutorial). However it
didn't work with the following command failing

`sudo ip link set wlp2s0 master br0` gives `Error: Device does not  allow enslaving to a bridge`

At this point I have no idea how to setup the networking properly
and also have no clue if I am missing something from the very beginning.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Does the guest interface have an IP address? Does the guest have a default route setup? Edit your youestion and add the info.

Comment: I'm having the same issue using qemu-system-riscv64 to emulate ArchLinux